# HTML5 ContentEditable: Where do this resize boxes come from in IE

Tags: html, contenteditable

I'm playing around with the `html5 contentEditable="true"` feature. The best example therefor is here [HTML5 Demo: ContentEditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable). Now this features works best in IE 9.0 (shocking, something works best in IE ;)), and there it displayes this cool resize boxes over all HTML elements (which is quite funny because now you can't click the button or any link^^ (well talk about wokring best...)).

I copied the demo and boiled it down to the content ediable part, **but I can't find how they make this resize boxes for the elements**. What am I missing?

Here is my code simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>HTML5 Demo: ContentEditable</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section contenteditable="true">
            <h2>Go ahead, edit away!</h2>
            <p>
                Here's a typical paragraph element
            </p>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    and now a list
                </li>
            </ol>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Source: [HTML5 Demo: ContentEditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable)

Comment: "shocking, something works best in IE" was never the problem... it was more like "shocking, something works *the same* in IE"

Comment: well this resize feature doesn't work in any other browser... IE currently has the "best" contentEditable implementation and afaik wrote the specification. Now I don't know if they just made an extra feature which nobody else will have (couldn't find documentation about it), or just extended it in a none standard conform way.....

Comment: IE had `contenteditable` at least three years before any other browsers and did a more thorough job. Other browsers have copied IE's functionality, to a greater or lesser extent, and specs have been written retrospectively (although not by Microsoft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla also has similar [resize handles for tables and images](http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/wmMaM/). WebKit and Opera have no built-in resizing UI for editable content. IE goes further and also provides resize handles for all elements that [have layout](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CGUQFjAA&url=http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html&ei=7yfoT4mVL8Sl8QPvu6jACg&usg=AFQjCNHMyhYsVpVv0XKD5DQmjrN5i7rHfw). IE also has a [different type of selection object](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/RangySelection#Control_selections_in_Internet_Explorer) to deal with editable elements being in this mode.

Comment: thanks for this interesting links. The thing I was missing is the 'document.designMode="on"' property in ie. This makes this resize boxes I was looking for. If you extend my example, so it sets the 'document.designMode = "on"', I will accept your answer :P (then I wont have to write it myself^^)